# Anchor HTML DIV tag to right of screen

Tags: layout, position, html

I have a site that has 2 DIV tags, one floats left the other floats right. The left DIV contains text for the page, the other DIV is used to display a video.

When I have text in the left DIV that fits the entire width of the screen the video shows up where I want it. However, a few pages have very little text and cause the video to show up in the right-center of the screen. I want to anchor this DIV to the right of the screen regardless of how much text is shown. I don't seem to get this problem in lower resolutions, it occurs more in the higher resolutions (such as 1280x1024). You can see an example on these pages:

http://www.quilnet.com/TechSupport.aspx - Positions the right DIV where I want it regardless of the resolution.

http://www.quilnet.com/ContactUs.aspx - Makes the right DIV closer to the center in higher resolutions. I want it in the position of the page TechSupport.aspx.

I am trying to refrain from using the width parameter because I want it to be resolutionally compliant. I don't want my viewers to have to move a scroll bar left and right.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Both links go to the same page :(

Comment: Fixed the link so it should be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have a table based layout, just put an 'align' attribute with a value of 'right' on the right hand TD tag, like this:

```
<td align="right" valign="top">...
```

Comment: Heh, wow. I feel like an idiot for not catching that. Thanks!